# In Tensorflow, a loss can be a tensor of more than one dimension. What does that mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

A scalar loss makes perfect sense to me which is in general what is fed as Loss Function in standard NN architectures. However there is a provision to make your loss not scalar, for example I had input a loss of size ([batch_size,]) and it did not throw an error.

Does it summarize the loss as sum/mean internally? It is not coming out very clear to me from the source code.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are trying to classify the MNIST data set. In this case, you have 10 output neurons. Therefore, after propagating a training sample through it, you get 10 activations. These have to be compared to the desired output via a cost function for each neuron (something like cross-entropy).

What you are trying to do here, is to minimize these costs among all the neurons. In the MNIST example you have to do something like

```
xent = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y), name="xent")
```

You see that the cost is calculated across all neurons as mean (reduce_mean).